# Custom Partitioner vs MultipleOutputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to map reduce, I would like to know what is the difference between creating multiple outputs based on certain conditions using a custom partitioner and MultipleOutputs concept in Map reduce.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it as the answer. Thxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a custom partitions, you will sent the data to a different reducer and each reducer will write one file with all the data processed by it.

```
part-r-00001, part-r-00002 . . .
```

With MiltipleOutputs each reducer will be available to write different files (Multiple outputs) with a custom name.

```
Tag1-r-00001, Tag2-r-00001, Tag1-r-00002, Tag2-r-00002 . . .
```

Customer partition is used to group related data together before the processing, and multiple outputs is to split the data in the output after the processing.

Using MultipleOutputs you will be able  to identify the data without need to keep the track of the reducer number and in the future if you need to increment or reduce the number of reduers (as the data change), you still will be able to identify the old data by the prefix.